# If a process has characteristic function in the following form, is the underlying process Markovian?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis

Given $T>0$ and a process $(X_{t})_{t\in [0,T]}$ such that the characteristic function is of the form

$$ \mathbb E_{x}\big[\exp(iuX_{T})\big\lvert\mathcal{F}_{t}\big]=\exp\big(\phi(T-t,u)X_{t}+\psi(T-t,u)\big),\; u \in \mathbb R,\; 0 \le t\le T,$$

where $\phi,\psi$ are continuous in the first component.

**Question**: Is $(X_{t})_{t\in [0,T]}$ Markovian?

**My attempt:** I know that the characteristic function of a real-valued random variable is the fourier transform of the underlying probability distribution function belonging to that random variable. The Markov property would be of the form for some bounded, real-valued $f$

$$ \mathbb E_{x}\big[f(X_{T})\lvert \mathcal{F}_{t}\big]= \mathbb E_{X_{t}}\big[f(X_{T})\big], \text{ a.s.},$$

so

$$\mathbb E_{x}\big[f(X_{T})\lvert \mathcal{F}_{t}\big]=\int_{\mathbb R}f(y)\phi_{X_{T}\lvert \mathcal{F}_{t}}(y)dy,$$

where

$$ \phi_{X_{T}\lvert \mathcal{F}_{t}}\text{ is the pdf of the random variable }\mathbb E\big[X_{T}\lvert\mathcal{F_{t}}\big].  $$

How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the process $X$ takes value in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $g \in L^1 (\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ and $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$f(x) := \int_\mathbb{R} g(u)e^{iux}\mathrm{d}u.$$
Let $t \in [0,T]$. By conditional Fubini theorem,
$$E[f(X_T)|\mathcal{F}_t] = \int_\mathbb{R} g(u)E[e^{iuX_t}|\mathcal{F}_t]\mathrm{d}u.$$
By your assumption, this is a function of $T-t$ and $X_t$ only.

The image of $L^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ by the Fourier transform is dense in $\mathcal{C_0}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ endowed with the norm $||\cdot||_\infty$, therefore in $L^1(\nu_T)$, where $\nu_T$ is the distribution of $X_T$. Hence, by the $L^1$-continuity of conditional expectation, the result extends to all functions $f$ in $L^1(\nu_T)$.

However, to have a Markov property, you need a stronger assumption in which the final time $T$ is replaced by any time $s \in [t,T]$.